# Jquery-Layout on android chrome, draggable not consistently visible while dragging

Tags: android, google-chrome

Tinkering with jquery draggables, jquery-layout and meteor here:

[edit] it's now at androiddragissue.meteor.com

On phone (G7100) in chrome the pic is draggable, but doesn't consistently appears "on top" despite high zindex.

Drag it out to the left, and it becomes visible, drag it back over the vertical center of the page, and it disappears.

I'm using a lib to use touch events as click, jquery.ui.touch-punch.min, which has worked nicely in the past.

Some coffee..

```
if Meteor.isClient
  Meteor.startup ->
    $(document).ready ->
      console.log !$('.ui-draggable'), new Date
      $('.face').draggable
        helper: (ev,ui) ->
          $(this).clone().appendTo("body")
          .css
            "z-index": 99999
            "position": 'absolute'
          .show()
```

The problem seems local to android, ios devices for instance work fine. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't get to your code (link fails).  Have it posted anywhere else?

Comment: teaches me. it's now at androiddragissue.meteor.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a Chrome for Android GPU layering bug. I'll try to create a reduced case & post a link to the ticket, but in the mean time, here's a workaround:

```
.face {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

As a bonus, this promotes the image to the GPU, making moving it around the page smoother.

Comment: Thanks a bundle. Didn't know you could do that, is it the css transform that does that or the translateZ(0)? [edit, I see it's the translateZ(0)]

Comment: I've created a ticket & reduced test case for this issue https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=215940

Comment: translateZ(0) gives an element its own GPU layer, my guess is the element with `overflow:auto` is getting its own layer when it shouldn't. I tried to explain what translateZ does at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h2djIdAFc5U&feature=youtu.be&t=24m40s